# How to automatically update a file on every git commit?

Tags: git, maven, glassfish

I want a file in my repository to be automatically updated (with any value, I just want its timestamp to be changed) with every git commit.  How can I do this?

My reason is to force my Glassfish appserver to reload my webapp when I build it on the server. I need to `touch` a file called `.reload` for this to happen. Rather than doing so manually, I want `git pull origin; mvn build` on my server to also `touch` the `.reload` file.

Comment: Can you put the burden in `mvn build` instead?

Comment: I could but I am also an mvn novice.

Comment: Have you looked at [git-hooks](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html)?

Comment: Agreed. Git hooks is the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[git-hooks](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html), thanks to the commenters on my question above, seems to be the way to go. maven cargo, thanks to the other answer, is a good way too; in fact, perhaps better for deployment, but if you want to do something more general git-hooks is better.

Answer (score 3):

You could just use the Maven Antrun Plugin or the Groovy Maven Plugin or even the Maven Exec Plugin to execute a touch of the .reload file. However you could also just deploy the application to the Glassfish server as part of a build using e.g. the Maven Cargo Plugin .. then you would not even have to touch the reload file because Maven would redeploy the app on the server as part of the build..